# Cannot connect to postgresql when starting h2o steam

Tags: postgresql, h2o

I have a problem when starting h2o's steam application: When following the accompanying manual, I create the `steam` db user:

```
createuser -P steam
```

and then

```
./create-database.sh
```

from the appropriate directory. And it seems fine. But when I try finally running steam with

```
./steam serve master --compilation-service-address="localhost:8080"
```

it fails with

```
pq: password authentication failed for user "steam"
```

I've tried modifying the `pg_hba.conf` with adding lines:

```
host steam steam 127.0.0.1/32 trust
local steam steam trust
```

but it didn't work. I've tried both `YARN` and the standalone `steam` version. Any ideas or workarounds will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created the ~/.pgpass file, where the file belongs to the user that is running Steam?

It should contain:  `*:*:*:steam:<your password>`
And also it should be only user readable `chmod 600 ~/.pgpass`

Comment: Thank you sir, I forgot about this option altogether.